# C# calling into managed C++ dll throws exception from timer callback but not a button handler

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop, managed

I have a third-party .dll written in managed C++ that wraps another third-party .dll written in unmanaged C++. I have the source to both.

I'm wrapping the managed .dll in C#. There's a function that I've written in the managed .dll called GetStatus. All it does it make one call to the unmanaged .dll, and then returns a byte array.

From the C# project, I call into the .dll like this (where `.Status()` is the function in the C++ .dll. This is in the quick-and-dirty state right now.)

```
IEnumerable<byte> GetDeviceStatus()
{
    byte[] st = device.Status();
    if (st != null && st.Length > 10)
    {
        return st.Where((s, i) => i > 1 && i < 10);
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<byte>();
}
```

Now here's the ridiculous part. I have a button handler that calls `GetDeviceStatus()`. Simple, you click the button, calls the function and uses the result to populate some stuff... that's it. Works like a charm every time.

When I move the call to `GetDeviceStatus()` into a `Windows.Forms.Timer` callback, I get a `AccessViolationException` from the managed C++ .dll with the message

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

It only happens from the timer callback. I thought initially it was because my device in the unmanaged .dll wasn't initialized yet, so I increased the timer interval to 10 seconds to no avail. Even if I click the button to call `GetDeviceStatus()` immediately on app start up, it will work every time.

This is the code in the managed C++ dll:

```
array<unsigned char>^ Status()
{ 
    ctrlMsg_t *ctrl;

    // create array of size of really transmitted additional data (depends on event type)
    array<unsigned char>^ buffer = gcnew array<unsigned char> (32);

    long lResult = inquiry_status(m_iFd, ctrl);

    if (lResult < 0)
    {
        throw gcnew CTRLException((eErrorCode)lResult, "Failed");
    }
    else
    {
        buffer[0] = ctrl->ctrl[0];
        buffer[1] = ctrl->ctrl[1];

        // copy data from buffer of base class
        for (unsigned int i = 2; i < 31; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = ctrl->data[i - 2];
        }

    }


    // return data array
    return buffer; 
}
```

Lastly, I thought maybe it was the unmanaged call in that function, so I changed the function to this just to test, and it still does the same thing.

```
array<unsigned char>^ Status()
{ 
    //ctrlMsg_t *ctrl;

    // create array of size of really transmitted additional data (depends on event type)
    array<unsigned char>^ buffer = gcnew array<unsigned char> (32);

    long lResult = 0;//inquiry_status(m_iFd, ctrl);

    if (false)
    {
        throw gcnew CTRLException((eErrorCode)lResult, "Failed");
    }
    else
    {
        /*buffer[0] = ctrl->ctrl[0];
        buffer[1] = ctrl->ctrl[1];*/

        // copy data from buffer of base class
        for (unsigned int i = 2; i < 31; i++)
        {
            //Just a random value for debugging purposes
            buffer[i] = 2;//ctrl->data[i - 2];
        }

    }


    // return data array
    return buffer; 
}
```

Why does it hate my timer so much?

**Edit:**

Through further testing, I've found that if I put the call to the dll in another thread and start the thread from the button handler, the same thing happens.

**More Info:**

If I include the managed C++ project into my solution, this whole issue goes away completely. I can't include the project in the production solution though so it's not really a viable alternative.

I changed the function completely to return just an integer (I chose 8) to C# and it worked in every scenario. There's something going wrong when I'm returning my `array<unsigned char>^` back to C# that only happens when the project is built and added as a .dll.

Comment: I believe the timer tick event runs on a different thread, perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: In fact it looks like it could be (This deals with System.Threading.Timer but my assumption is it is the same issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622708/access-violation-with-unmanaged-dll

Comment: @DaveZych That was my immediate thought when I first saw the issue. I  dismissed it though because I (incorrectly?) assumed that `Forms.Timer`s executed their callbacks on the same thread as the GUI. After I posted my question, I tested calling the function through the button click on another thread and it crashed again. It seems that this IS a threading issue, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure you can solve it using the `Timer` as I don't think there's a way to force it to use the GUI thread. Depending on what you're doing you could write your own quick and dirty timer if that will suffice.

Comment: I added some more information because I don't know that it's a threading issue, but it sort of is at the same time...

Comment: Very hard to guess at, a call from a timer's Tick event handler is not different from a button's Click event handler.  Enable unmanaged debugging and show us the stack trace when the AVE is thrown.